# Render Checkboxes in form modifier grid in Magento2 Admin

Tags: magento2, grid, modifier

I'm building a feature where I need to render checkboxes for a set of comma-separated values in a column.

Here's my existing code:

```
protected function fillModifierMeta()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getTextColumn('id', false, 'Product ID', 10),
            'product_sku' => $this->getTextColumn('product_sku', false, 'Product SKU', 20),
            'product_name' => $this->getTextColumn('product_name', false, 'Product Name', 30),
            'product_supplier_sku' => $this->getTextColumn('product_supplier_sku', false, 'Supplier SKU', 40),
            'available_qty' => $this->getTextColumn('available_qty', false, 'Available Qty', 50),
            'received_qty' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                            'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'received_qty',
                            'label' => __('Receive Qty'),
                            'fit' => true,
                            'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                            'sortOrder' => 60,
                            'validation' => [
                                'validate-number' => true,
                                'validate-greater-than-zero' => true,
                                'required-entry' => true,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'actionDelete' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'additionalClasses' => 'data-grid-actions-cell',
                            'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                            'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                            'label' => __('Actions'),
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'fit' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Which renders it like this:
[image]

Now, I want to add a field to this called `barcodes` which contains value such as `EG6F2,A4GT5,EF58T,Y1W3R`. I want to render these as selectable checkboxes in the column.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the whole code from where you called fillModifierMeta function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to accomplish this. If anyone is interested this is how you can do it:

```
'barcodes' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Form\Element\CheckboxSet::NAME,
                            'options' => [
                                ['label' => 'test', 'value' => 'test'],
                                ['label' => 'test', 'value' => 'test1']
                            ],
                            'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'barcodes',
                            'label' => __('Barcodes'),
                            'fit' => true,
                            'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => true
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
```